# Rigify prefix issue

Tags: animation, armature, bones, rigify, vertex-weights

When I parent the model with the generated rigify armature, it doesn't deform the model, I think it's because the bone names are changed with the prefix "DEF-".

The model already has weights and I don't want to change the name of each bone of the models.
Is there a way to generate the armature without the prefix?